# Importing any .*pyd fails in my python and throws an import errror: the specified could not be found

Tags: python, pyd

I am developing a python project on pyprosail which gives the crop canopy reflectance based on 14 paramaters. The code is already written [here](https://pyprosail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

What I have to do is download pyprosail and import it as a module in my project. But I am facing this error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have tried:
1. Switching to python 32 bit version as the compiled dll was 32-bit.
2. Downloading the lower version of python as I have come to known that this supports only python 2.7.
3. Checking the pyd dependency on dependency walker which gives a whole lot of 1000s of dlls missing.
4. Trying to modify the import statement as it throw a ValueError.
5. Modifying the System PATH variable.

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyprosail\PyProSAIL.py", line 18, in 
>           import _prosail_model
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

And here is the piece of code from PyProSAIL.py:

```
##from . import _prosail_model
import _prosail_model # this statement throws error
import numpy as np

# Common leaf distributions
Planophile = (1, 0)
Erectophile = (-1, 0)
Plagiophile = (0, -1)
Extremophile = (0, 1)
Spherical = (-0.35, -0.15)
Uniform = (0, 0)

def run(N, chloro, caroten, brown, EWT, LMA, psoil, LAI, hot_spot, solar_zenith, solar_azimuth, view_zenith, view_azimuth, LIDF):
```